# Problemas ao inserir dados em uma tabela no MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Não consigo inserir dados na minha tabela, e os comandos estão todos certos, conexão certa, mas não insere os dados. Já refiz a tabela para ver se era algum erro de configuração ou de nome, mas continua do mesmo jeito

Segue o código:

```php
<?php

include 'conexao.php';
include 'script/password.php';

$nomeusuario = $_POST['nomeusuario'];
$mail = $_POST['mailusuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senhausuario'];
$nivel = $_POST['nivelusuario'];
$status = 'Ativo';

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome_usuario,mail_usuario,senha_usuario,nivel_usuario,status) values ('$nomeusuario','$mail',sha1('$senha'),$nivel,'$status')";

$inserir = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

?>
```

Comment: Qual erro aparece na sua tela?

Comment: Faz um echo $sql; e tenta rodar o resultado em texto direto no banco e envia a mensagem de erro para gente analisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha eu sempre preferi usar o PDO para conectar no banco, vou te dar um exemplo de como você pode utilizar o PDO ao invés de utilizar o mysqli.

O Seu arquivo conexao.php ficaria assim

```
<?php

$dns = "mysql:dbname=nomeDoBanco;host=localhost"; //informe o nome do banco e o local
$dbuser = "usuario"; //informe o usuario
$dbpass = "senha"; //informe a senha

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dns, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

já o seu segundo de trecho de código seria assim

```
<?php

//alterar para include_once pois caso o arquivo já esteja incluído ele não fara a inclusão novamente.
include_once('conexao.php'); 
include_once('script/password.php');

//adicionar o "addslashes" pois já ajuda um pouco contra injeção de SQL
$nomeusuario = addslashes($_POST['nomeusuario']);
$mail = addslashes($_POST['mailusuario']);
$senha = addslashes($_POST['senhausuario']);
$nivel = addslashes($_POST['nivelusuario']);
$status = 'Ativo';

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome_usuario, mail_usuario, senha_usuario, nivel_usuario, status) values ('$nomeusuario', '$mail', sha1('$senha'), $nivel, '$status')";

$sql = $pdo->query($sql);

?>
```

utilizando esta forma qualquer erro de inclusão no banco sera exibido de forma clara e você conseguira facilmente tratar.